# Perl 6: Backslashes in transliteration (tr///)

Tags: raku, transliteration

I noticed while experimenting with `tr///`, that it doesn't seem to translate backslashes, even when escaped. For example,

```perl6
say TR"\^/v"." given 'v^/\\';
say TR"\\^/v"." given 'v^/\\';
say TR"\ ^/v"." given 'v^/\\';
```

All of them [output](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7/784sVIhJEgpJk6/TElPSSE9syw1T0G9LE4/JkbdmgsmS0BaAav0//8A) `...\` rather than what I expected, `....`

There's some other weird behaviour too, like `\` seemingly [only escaping lowercase letters](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7/784sVIhJEgpJjEmLkY/pkxJT0khPbMsNU9BvSxOPzEmRt36/38A), but the [docs page](https://docs.perl6.org/syntax/tr$SOLIDUS$SOLIDUS$SOLIDUS) doesn't have much information... What exactly is the behaviour of backslashes (`\`) in transliteration (`tr///`)?

Comment: I don't think any of the user doc aspects of [this gist](https://gist.github.com/raiph/a9d58825662b5cf2da2cc550cb3c6989) helps but perhaps the links to roast tests and code at the end do

Comment: It appears to me like a bug in the undocumented 'cc' role in QGrammar that gets used by the tr/// operator
https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/master/src/Perl6/Grammar.nqp#L5333

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a bug caused by backslashes getting swallowed instead of correctly escaping things in the grammar for tr///.

```
say TR/\\// given '\\'
===SORRY!=== Error while compiling:
Malformed replacement part; couldn't find final /
at line 2
------> <BOL>⏏<EOL>
```

I have raised https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/issues/2456 and submitted https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/pull/2457 which fixes it.

The second part of the answer is that Perl 6 tries quite hard in some quoting constructs to only interpret `\` as an escape for valid escape sequences, i.e. `\n`, `\r`, `\s`, `\'`, etc. Otherwise it is left as a literal `\`.

Answer (score 3):

I do not have an explanation for the observed problem. However, when you use the Perl 6 [`Str.trans`](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/trans#(Str)_method_trans) method it looks like it's working as expected:

```
say 'v^/\\'.trans( "\\^/v" => "." );
```

[Outputs](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7/784sVJBvSxOPyZGXa@kKDGvWENBKSYmTr9MScHWTkFJT0lB05oLpCgkCCoOFErPLEvNg2lDSOOXVcAq/f8/AA):

```
....
```

Reference:

- https://perl6advent.wordpress.com/2010/12/21/day-21-transliteration-and-beyond/

Comment: I know about the `trans` routine (I could even use `s:g///` if I wanted to be more regexey), but my question is specifically regarding the behaviour of `tr///`. `trans` simply takes `Pair`s, and the strings and regexes are evaluated on the usual way beforehand.